# How to copy web part pages between document libraries?

Tags: 2010, document-library, web-part-page

I have a web part page "DocLib1.aspx" in document library "DobLib1" and it has a few web parts.

How can I take the same web part page and copy it to other document libraries? There are about 50+. The web part page is named after the document library (with aspx extension). One of the web parts is the list for the same doc lib where the web part is residing.

Comment: @Sally: Don't be disheartened by not receiving an answer quickly. Some questions are harder than others and people that know the answer to your question may not have seen it yet. Thanks and welcome to SharePoint Overflow!

Comment: Is there an option to do this on SharePoint publishing sites? I don't have access to the server to install any of these utilities. I need to move web part pages between document libraries without losing any of the web parts (which is what the Move action in the Manage Content area seems to do).

Answer (score 2):

The [content deployment wizard](http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/) is one option but you would need to do it 50+ times so probably not the best use of your time. I think your will need to do some sort of scripting against the object model for this to work. Is that a possibility for you?

There is [SPFile.CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.copyto.aspx) method which is probably what you are going to have to do on the web part page to copy it to your destination libraries. Have a look at the [SPFileCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfilecollection.aspx) object too.

Answer (score 2):

The free edition of [CopyMove for SharePoint](http://www.sharepointproducts.com) can do this for SharePoint 2007. The SP2010 version is coming later this year.